# Не получается очистить SharedPreferences через диалог

Tags: java, android

Я решил в своё приложение c календарём и заметками добавить функцию очистки SharedPreferences(в котором и хранятся заметки) через диалог, но кое-что пошло не так: заметки должны были очищатся при нажатии на кнопку "ОК" в диалоге, но очистка почему-то не происходит(никаких ошибок не вылезало), даже не смотря на то, что я это потдверждал следующей командой:

```
editor.apply();
```

Код activity_notes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="Notes">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="83dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/addnote"

        android:onClick="addnote"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="279dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="324dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/final_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notesView"
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="468dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/clear_notes"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="335dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="335dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="538dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/delete_notes"
        android:onClick="clear_notes"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Код Notes.java(Если что, код очистки заметок в методе `clear_notes`):

```
package com.masterok.calendar;



import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;


import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class Notes extends AppCompatActivity {

    final Context context = this;
    final Context context1 = this;
    public ImageButton button;
    public TextView final_text;
    public SharedPreferences pref;
    public EditText input_text;
    public TextView notesView;
    public final String save_key = "save note";





    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes);

        notesView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.notesView);
        button = findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        final_text =  findViewById(R.id.final_text);

        init();}

    public void init(){
        pref = getSharedPreferences( "note",MODE_PRIVATE);
        input_text = findViewById (R.id.input_text);
        notesView.setText(pref.getString(save_key,"You haven`t got any note"));

    }

    public void clear_notes(View arg0){

        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context1);
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.deleting_notes, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder mDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context1);
        mDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
        mDialogBuilder
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(save_key, MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                                editor.apply();
                                editor.remove(save_key );
                                editor.apply();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = mDialogBuilder.create();

        alertDialog.show();
    }



        public void addnote(View arg0) {

            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompt, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder mDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            mDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

            final EditText userInput = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.input_text);

            mDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                    final_text.setText(userInput.getText());
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
                                    edit.putString(save_key,final_text.getText().toString());
                                    edit.apply();
                                    notesView.setText(pref.getString(save_key,"You haven`t got any note"));
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

            
            AlertDialog alertDialog = mDialogBuilder.create();

           
            alertDialog.show();
            }


}
```

Код prompt.xml(Это диалог добавления заметки):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/write_the_note"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Код deleting_notes.xml(Это диалог очистки заметок):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/do_you_want_to_clear_notes" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Скажите пожалуйста, как исправить эту проблему.

Comment: getSharedPreferences( "note",MODE_PRIVATE)` и `getSharedPreferences(save_key, MODE_PRIVATE)` - разницу видите? Вы очищаете другой преференс (с другим именем).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрев на комментарий от пользователя [woesss](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11515/woesss), я нашёл ответ на мой вопрос.
Проблема была в моём коде(в файле `Notes.java`, в методе `init`), а именно в этой строчке: `pref = getSharedPreferences( "note",MODE_PRIVATE);` В этой строке я пытался получить SharedPreferences, который я не создавал. Вместо этой ошибочной строчки должно быть вот, что: `getSharedPreferences(save_key, MODE_PRIVATE);` Когда я это исправил, проблема исчезла. Если у вас тоже будет такая же проблема, то этот ответ может вам помочь.